# Why is $\kappa(A) = \infty$ if $A$ is a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, condition-number

Al though not important for my course, I was curious as to why the condition number of a singular matrix is $\infty$. Which also begs the question of what the condition number of a non-invertible non-square matrix would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition number is defined as the ratio between the highest and smallest singular value of the matrix.

If the matrix is singular, then the smallest singular value is $0$.

Thus, the condition numbers tends to $\infty$.

Comment: And what if the matrix is not a square matrix but a a $m \times n$ matrix with no inverse? What would the condition number be?

Comment: @MariaTakahashi Then, in the definition of the condition number, replace inverse with pseudoinverse. ([Condition number of a rectangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/375421/318073))